# django filebrowser upload failed

Tags: python, django, apache, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I have installed a django application with django-tinymce and django-filebrowser. In my machine every thing works fine. when I deployed the application to the production, filebrowser fails to upload file and it shows me the error message `Failed`

Here is my settings

> MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/staticFiles/APCC/'
>
> MEDIA_URL = '/static/APCC/'
>
> STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/staticFiles'
>
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and here is my apache configs

> ```
> <Location "/">
>     SetHandler python-program
>     PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
>     SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE APCC.settings
>     PythonDebug Off
>     PythonOption django.root /srv/APCC
>     PythonPath "['/srv/APCC/'] + sys.path"
> </Location>
>     Alias "/static/" "/srv/www/staticFiles/"
>     <Location "/static">
>             SetHandler None
>             Order deny,allow
>             Allow from all
>     </Location>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I have make sure that the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory is created and the uploads folder required by the filebrowser is also created under it.

Also the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory and the uploads directories have write permissions.

I believe the problem is in my apache configuration or file structure. where would be the problem? also is there any logs specific for tinycme or filebrowser to check?

Comment: What is the entire error message?

Comment: I do not see any error message. Just the word Failed appears to me.

Comment: Sorry Pavel, I checked apache error logs and found this line at the end of uploading process (TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str, referer: http://myhost:8000/srv/APCC/admin/filebrowser/upload/?type=image&pop=2)

Comment: The backslash at the end of `MEDIA_ROOT` bothers me (..APCC/'\\).

Comment: It is a typing mistake while posting the question. I tried this (MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/staticFiles/APCC') and this (MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/staticFiles/APCC/') and the result is the same

Comment: Does it work without apache? Through `python manage.py runserver  myhost:8080`. If it doesn't, we'll get a full stacktrace at least. If it does, then the problem is with apache configuration. Do you get a descriptive error page if you set `DEBUG = True` in your settings?

Comment: it does work without apache and I set DEBUG=True but I did not get any error page. I see the word Failed only

Comment: Let's try `PythonDebug On` in apache settings.

Comment: I have turned on PythonDebug in the apache configs but I did not where to check the logs. I checked the errors.log and the same previous error appear

Comment: How large is the file you're trying to upload? Is `LimitRequestBody` set anywhere in apache?

Comment: the file size is 40kb and there is not LimitRequestBody settings in any of my apache config files

Comment: I had reconfigured apahce with mod_wsgi instead of mod_python and every thing works fine. It seems that the problem was with mod_python as it is deprecated. Thnx Pavel for your help